# Регулярное выражение соотвествующие второму вхождению первого слова в файле?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Допустим есть 3 текстовых файла со следующим содержимым:

1. кот *какой-то текст* кот *какой-то текст*".
2. лиса *какой-то текст* лиса *какой-то текст*".
3. собака *какой-то текст* собака *какой-то текст*".

У меня 2 вопроса:

1. Возможное ли составить такое выражение, чтобы оно находило только второе вхождение слова, которое всегда стоит первым в файле?

   1. кот *какой-то текст* **кот** *какой-то текст*".
   2. лиса *какой-то текст* **лиса** *какой-то текст*".
   3. собака *какой-то текст* **собака** *какой-то текст*".
2. Мне нужно произвести замену второго вхождения слова. Причем заменить первым словом в транслите (сам сомневаюсь что это можно сделать используя только регулярные выражения).

В результате мне нужно получить следующее содержимое файлов:

1. кот *какой-то текст* kot *какой-то текст*".
2. лиса *какой-то текст* lisa *какой-то текст*".
3. собака *какой-то текст* sobaka *какой-то текст*".

Возможно ли составить регулярное выражение для такого?

Comment: *Причем заменить первым словом в транслите (сам сомневаюсь что это можно сделать используя только регулярные выражения)* - Верно сомневаетесь, это невозможно сделать только регуляркой.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  а что насчет первого вопроса? Такое возможно?

Comment: В Notepad++: `\A(\s*(\w+)[\s\S]*?)\2([\s\S]*)` --> `$1KOT$3`.